# Is there a Pythagorean triple where the sum of the squares of all three members of the triple is itself a perfect square?

Tags: number-theory, pythagorean-triples

I am trying to create a problem for my students where they are essentially finding the length of a 3D vector.  I wanted the problem to only use whole numbers/perfect squares.

In the problem they are given a rectangular prism where they need to use Pythagoras' Theorem to find the diagonal of the base and they are then to use this measurement and the height to find the diagonal of the whole prism.  What dimensions can I make the prism so that its side lengths, and both the diagonal of the base and the diagonal of the prism are all whole numbers?

Comment: Base 3,4 diagonal 5. Then height 12, diagonal of prism 13. Is it ok?

Comment: "The sum of the squares of all three members of the (Pythagorean) triple" as in $a^2+b^2+c^2$, where $a^2+b^2=c^2$? Then that means $a^2+b^2+c^2 = 2c^2$ has to be a perfect square. Then $\sqrt 2$ has to be rational.

Comment: If you want more complicate numbers. Base 5,12 diagonal 13. Then height 84, diagonal of prism 85.

Comment: Lists of Pythagorean Triples are available on-line.  What you need is for the "hypotenuse" of one triple to be a "leg" of another:  the $ \ 3-4-5 \ , \ 5 - 12 - 13 \ $ set is probably the easiest to deal with for students without a calculator, but there are an infinite number of such pairs. (Yet another set is $ \ 8 - 15 - 17 \ , \ 17 - 144 - 145 \ \ . \ ) $

Comment: What is the diagonal of a prism?

Comment: From a pedagogical perspective (I'm a science teacher, not a math teacher)... By the time they're working with 3D vectors, they should be well past the Pythagorean theorem in terms of knowledge and ability. Why not just present them with $a^2+b^2+c^2=d^2$ and note that it looks a lot like the Pythagorean theorem, because it's just extending it an extra dimension?

Comment: @peterwhy Yes, his title seems to imply $a^2+b^2+c^2$ of a Pythagorean triple $a,b,c$. But that is $$(m^2-n^2)^2+(2mn)^2+(m^2+n^2)^2 = 2(m^2+n^2)^2$$ hence is never a square. I wonder what he really meant?

Answer (score 2):

There are an infinite number of these triple. All that is needed is to replace the hypotenuse of one triple with the odd leg of a larger triple. This, plus the even leg of he larger triple forms a Pythagorean quadruple such as:
$$(3,4,5)+(5,12,13)\longrightarrow(2,4,12,13)$$

The process can be continued indefinitely since the odd leg can be any odd value greater than one, e.g.

$$3,4,12,84,3612,6526884,6526885)$$
$$
(33,56,65)+(65,72,97)\\
+(97,4704,4705)+(4705,442728,442753)\\
=(33,56,72,4704,442728,442753)
$$

Comment: [OEIS sequence A127690](https://oeis.org/A127690) $3, 4, 12, 84, 3612, 6526884, 21300113901612,\dots.$ a(1)=3; for n>1, a(n) is such that a(1)^2+...+a(n)^2 = (1+a(n))^2.